# Strict Typescript while using sinon in a convenient way

Tags: typescript, jestjs, sinon

I want `"strict": true,` to be on in my ts config file, but this is causing me some inconveniences for my tests.  Specifically, if I have code like this:

```
    const mockSnapshot = {};
    sinon.stub(loadData, 'loadData').returns(mockSnapshot);
```

I get a TS error on the second line that says:

[image]

In this test, the structure of mockSnapshot is irrelevant.

I want type checking elsewhere in my tests, but when it comes to sinon, I think I'd prefer it to allow anything.  I noticed I can add `// @ts-ignore` before the line with the error and the error will go away, but I don't want to have to litter this before every line that uses sinon.

Is there a best of both worlds situation, where I can say I want sinon to be lax, but I want everywhere else to be strict (without littering my code with ts-ignores)?

Comment: You could make it an `any` type: `const mockSnapshot:any = {};`

Comment: Another thing is to make an interface for it `interface MyInterface {/*Interface properties/functions*/}` then `const mockSnapshot: MyInterface = {};`

Comment: A third thing is to install the [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sinon), and use the type that relates to `mockSnapshot`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm trying to *not* do that 3rd suggestion because the type requires so many fields that it'll obscure the point of the test.